# How to use big fun 'play the lottery' card

Tags: monopoly

In the Monopoly-like/clone [America-in-a-Box](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14959/america-box) (and other *-opolies by Late for the Sky), when I play the card "Play the Lottery!", if I choose "three" as my number, then if I rolled a 3 on the first die and a 4 on second die, is it possible to count only the first die to collect my prize or do I need to count the total of both dice to continue?

[image: Big Fun- play the lottery]

Comment: @ilkkachu Actually, it looks like the number you choose has no effect on the payout.  If you place $50 and roll your number, you get $500 back, regardless of what that number was.  So there's no good reason to choose any number other than *exactly* 7, which is the most common roll on 2d6.  Sure, you could say and roll 12 and get really lucky, but the payout is the same, so why wouldn't you pick the most likely outcome?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, doh, indeed, the only choice is how much you can risk for the bet. I somehow managed to read it as "collect that many times the amount you placed". I've seen a similar one in some other game where it was "choose N, get N times some stuff if you roll >= N", which seems to make more sense in allowing you to go big or safe.

Comment: Is this supposed to be broken? Bet money for 16% chance of 10x payoff; e becomes 1.16.

Comment: @Joshua I think it's ok / normal that an event that you an only use a specific times (when you draw this card?) has a positive EV - otherwise, what would be the point of using this option if it has neutral or negative EV? What I am more concerned is that it seems like the game designer does not understand that not all numbers are equally likely with 2 D6 rolls ... or it's a gotcha by design, which I think would be even worse from a game design perspective.

Comment: @Joshua (that said, it's still not good design any way you turn it because the optimal strategy clearly becomes "always gamble when you can", not much tension in that decision)

Comment: @xLeitix Just because the expected value of the *money* is positive doesn't mean that the expected value of the *utility* is positive. If losing means that you won't be able to afford rent if you land on an opponent's space next turn, you probably shouldn't gamble.

Comment: @xLeitix Yeah, I'd redesign that to either just use 1d6 and halve the payout, or alternatively use 1d12, but Monopoly sets don't usually come with a d12, so you'd have to supply your own.  Anything using 2+ dice is going to make it pointless to bet on anything other than the most likely outcome.  It does seem as though gambling isn't an option though - when you draw this card, you *must* gamble, your only choice is how much you want to put on the line.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I don't see why you couldn't bet $0.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, that's another weakness in design.  I'd modify it to have a minimum bet as well.  Maybe $10?  Otherwise the card could just do nothing and be pointless.  I feel like every card should be required to have *some* effect regardless of circumstances.

Answer (score 14):

Given you can only choose the range of numbers that can be made by adding the values from a pair of standard Monopoly dice, *and* that no other rules in Monopoly use a single dice for their actions (at least, as far I am aware), then it's **heavily** implied you need to use the total of both dice here.

Answer (score 6):

No. If the dice come up 3 and 4, then you have rolled a seven and only collect if you called for seven.